# Prove $\log_7 n$ is either an integer or irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, rationality-testing

I have been trying to prove a certain claim and have hit a wall. Here is the claim...

> **Claim:** If $n$ is a positive integer then
>               $\log_{7}n$ is an integer or it is irrational

*Proof (so far)*: Let $y=\log_{7}n$. Note that to say
                    $n$ is a positive integer is equivalent
                    to saying that n is a non-zero natural
                    number. We will proceed by trying
                    to prove the contrapositive.

*Claim (alternate version):* If $y$ is
                    a rational number and is not an integer,
                    then either $n$ is zero or it is not a
                    natural number.

Given the above we can assume that there
                    exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that $y$ equals
                    the quotient of $a$ over $b$. We can also
                    assume from the premises that $b$ does not
                    equal one and that $a$ and $b$ are relatively
                    prime. Note thus that $n$ may be considered
                    equal to seven raised to the power of $a$
                    over $b$. Further note that because of this
                    $n$ cannot be zero or negative. To prove 
                    the claim, one must prove that $n$ is not
                    a natural number.

*Where I am stuck:* How can I guarantee from here that $n$
                       is not a natural number? Is there any
                       way to concretely ensure that there are
                       no integers $a$ and $b$ such that the
                       fractional exponent above will never give
                       an integer when raising seven to its power?

I have been trying to play around with
                       a proof that there is no such thing
                       as a rational root of a prime number, but
                       that hasn't shook anything loose so far.

Comment: Is `\log_7n` meant to be $\log_7 n$?

Comment: Yes. I am having a little trouble with the LaTeX.

Comment: Johnq, I hope your question looks okay now. Sorry for all the editing.

Answer (score 11):

Suppose $\log_7 n =\frac{p}{q}$ is rational, then $7^{p/q}=n$, raising both sides to the $q^{\text{th}}$ power, we see that $7^p=n^q$. Now we have by unique prime factorization that $n=7^k$ for some integer $k$, since it divides $7^p$. But then $7^p=7^{kq}$, or $p=kq$, but then $\frac{p}{q}=k$ is an integer as desired.

Comment: Are you starting from my original claim?

Comment: @Johnq yes, I'm showing that if $\log_7 n$ is rational, it must be an integer.

Answer (score 3):

Usually negative statements are proven by contradiction.

The definition of an irrational number is a number which is **not** rational. This suggest that you should try contradiction.

**Proof start**

Assume by contradiction that $\log_7 (n) =\frac{a}{b}$ with $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ and $b \nmid a$.

This implies that 
$$7^{\frac{a}{b}}=n$$
or 
$$n^b=7^a$$

What does this tell you about the prime factorisation of $n$? From here it should be easy.

Comment: So would you say that the contrapositive in this case was the wrong way to go?

Comment: I am a bit stumped at what you mean by "what does this tell you about the prime factorization of n". I see that 7 divides $n^b$ ,but from there I don't see what that says about n, a, or b.

Comment: Would it suggest that n can only be comprised of roots of 7?

Comment: @Johnq Contrapositive probably also works. But most of the times if contrapositive works, so does contradiction.

Comment: @Johnq If $p |n$ then $p|n^b=7^a$. This shows that the only prime dividing $n$ is $7$.

Comment: Ok, let me see if I get this straight....

Since I have assumed that y is a rational number that is not an integer, n can not be a multiple of n by the definition of y. Thus, since the result that you led to implies that the only primes which compose n are 7's, a contradiction is reached. is that right?

Comment: @Johnq If the only prime dividing $n$ is $7$ it follows that $n=7^k$ for some positive integer. Then $\log_7(n)=k$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The contrapositive is an awkward approach to take in this problem, because the alternatives are $\log_7 n$ is either an integer or irrational in the conclusion.

So the contrapositive would be to assume $\log_7 n$ is a rational number which is not an integer, and then try to prove $n$ is not a positive integer.

An approach using the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) seems easier to explain.

Let's assume that $n$ is a positive integer and that $x = k/m$ is rational, i.e. the ratio of two coprime integers, say $m \gt 0$, and then show that in fact $x$ would have to be an integer.  Note that:

$$ x = \log_7 n \implies 7^x = 7^{k/m} = n \implies n^m - 7^k = 0 $$

Now $n$ satisfies a polynomial.  If $k \ge 0$, then this polynomial has integer coefficients, and since the leading coefficient is one, any rational root $n$ would have to be an integer of the form $n \mid 7^k$.  Since $n$ is known to be a positive integer, then $n = 7^d$ for some integer $d$ between $0$ and $k$, and thus $x = \log_7 n = d$ is an integer.

On the other hand, suppose $k \lt 0$.  Then we convert the above to an integer polynomial by multiplying by $7^{-k}$:

$$  7^{-k} n^m - 1 = 0 $$

Now the Rational Roots Theorem says $n$ must have the form $\frac{\pm 1}{7^d}$ where $d$ is an integer between $0$ and $-k$.  But we have assumed $n$ is a positive integer (in this proof by contradiction), so the sign of $n$ must be positive and $d$ must be zero.  That is, $n=1$ and $x = \log_7 n = 0$, which is an integer.

Therefore if $n$ is a positive integer, then $x = \log_7 n$ is either irrational or it is an integer.  **QED**

Comment: What part of this serves as the proof that n could be irrational?

Comment: As I explain in the opening paragraph, my preferred approach is not a strict *contrapositive* as you tried to pursue.  I agree with what you state as the strict contrapositive, restating this in the second paragraph.  In the fourth paragraph I give the logically equivalent statement, in which we will assume both $\log_7 n$ is rational and $n$ is a positive integer, and prove that then $\log_7 n$ is an integer.

Comment: _ny rational root  would have to be an integer of the form ∣7_ could you please explain why it that?

Comment: @Andrew: Welcome to Math.SE!  The [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) says in the special case that the leading coefficient of a polynomial is $1$, any rational root of that polynomial must be an integer.  Here we have $n^m - 7^k = 0$, so $n$ is a root of that *monic* polynomial.  Thus $n$ would have to be an integer (and divide $7^k$) *if* $n$ were rational.