# Prove if $n$ is a positive integer $\log_7(n)$ is an integer or irrational

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I found this answer:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1393378

But I don't get it. Aren't we trying to prove that $\space \log_7(n) \space$ is irrational. Even if we were trying to prove the contrapositive, shouldn't proving $\space \log_7(n) \space$ is rational imply that $n$ is not a positive integer?! I'm really lost. Maybe I should go back to basics. Can someone please help me!

Comment: Irrational and "not rational" are the same thing. The answer is saying that if $\log_7(n)$ is rational, then $\log_7(n)$ must be an integer. In other words, $\log_7(n)$ can't be "strictly rational", such as $\frac{3}{2}$, $\frac{10}{21}$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

That answer uses a [proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction), not a contrapositive. Just about every proof that a number is irrational uses that strategy. @jgon assumes $\log_7n$ is rational and derives a contradiction from that assumption, and therefore $\log_7n$ isn't rational, i.e. is irrational because all real numbers are either rational or irrational.

Comment: And hence we proved that I should go back to the basics. Appreciate the answer anyway.

Comment: What's the contradiction in jgon's answer?! He proved that p/q is an integer but how is that a contradiction?!

Comment: @user971985 To be pedantic, jgon's answer gives a direct proof (i.e. one involving no contradiction) that if $\log_7n$ is rational it's an integer. But your question was about how we prove it's irrational when not an integer. We can restate that as "if rational then an integer", since as I mentioned "irrational" is equivalent for real numbers to "not rational". So for your purposes, the problem is to prove that if $\log_7n$ isn't an integer it's not rational either. In that case, we force a contradiction of our assumptions viz. $\log_7n=p/q,\,(p,\,q)=1\implies q=1\implies\log_7n\in\Bbb Z$.