# Soft question: prerequisites/brush up for "Mathematics for Computer Science" course

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, soft-question

I am looking to self-learn discrete maths to gain a more solid foundation of computer science. And so I started with a book that is often recommended from MIT OCW called [Mathematics for Computer Science](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9888407066). This is supposed to be an introductory Discrete Math course, and from [its site](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/) it says: *This course covers elementary discrete mathematics for computer science and engineering.*. I have a bit of a math background from about ten years ago, and I made my way through calculus, differential equations, and linear algebra.

However, on literally the first exercise I am totally lost and in looking up work-out solutions I don't even have the necessary background to be able to solve it even if I could. Here is the question:

> **Problem 1.6** 
> Show that $log_{7}n$ is either an integer or irrational, where n is a positive integer. Use whatever familiar facts about integers and primes you need, but explicitly state such facts.

There are a few answers on MathExchange (one here: [Prove $\log_7 n$ is either an integer or irrational](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393360/prove-log-7-n-is-either-an-integer-or-irrational)) proving with things such as "Rational Roots Theorem" or "Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic" or "Unique Prime Factorization" and others. However, I'm not knowledgeable of any of those (outside of being able to factor a number into its primes of course).

What might be a good place to start so that I can work my way through these exercises with the necessary prerequisites and knowledges to solve them? I don't expect to know everything, but if the first problem is way over my head then I'd like to get a better foundation so I can work through the problems and not just look them up.

I used to love math so much and I'd like to get back into it, but also have the necessary path forward so I don't just feel stuck -- thank you!

Comment: Maybr some college algebra and discrete mathematics?

Comment: @SeanRoberson but the above is suppose to be an introductory Discrete Mathematics course. Added a link to the course which says "This course covers elementary discrete mathematics for computer science and engineering"

Comment: For a very basic introduction proofs in the context of questions such as you gave, see the first 5 chapters of [**Numbers: Rational and Irrational**](https://users.auth.gr/siskakis/Niven-NumbersRationalAndIrrational.pdf) by Ivan Niven. By "very basic", I mean well below books such as [Solow's](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1118164024) and [Velleman's](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1108439535), namely something actually designed for (relatively strong, but not necessarily math-competition level) high school students (U.S. level; certainly lower level than one would expect of MIT caliber students).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro thanks for that info. Will the **Numbers** book cover things like those three theorems I mentioned? Are there any other books/courses that might help (do you think College Algebra here would be helpful at all?) Maybe this book might seem silly but I was thinking maybe this would be a good brush-up book: https://www.amazon.com/Everything-Pre-Algebra-Algebra-Notebook-Notebooks/dp/1523504382/. Or do you think that wouldn't help at all?

Comment: A glance at the table of contents of the Niven book will show it covers those results quite early. Also, regarding "Problem 1.6", see around pp. 69-70, this being near the end of what I suggested this book for. It should be very easy reading, and the exercises should be mostly do-able and instructive for your situation. FYI, I read and understood at least the first 5 chapters when I was taking a first school course in algebra (end of the year we got to quadratic equations), although I was working through our school's algebra-2/trig text at the time (2 years later course, which I never took).

Comment: The book you cited for possible brush-up seems fine, but this won't have the kinds of theoretical topics you asked about. However, if you feel that you need to review aspects of "mechanical skills" school algebra (e.g. factoring trinomials and such, polynomial multiplication, basic work with numerical and algebraic fractions, etc.) then it seems reasonably decent. However, after the book you cited comes algebra 2 and college algebra level topics, after which (unless a very strong course) comes precalculus topics that would include things like the rational roots theorem and logarithms.

Comment: Regarding irrationality proofs using the rational roots theorem (done in Niven's book; by the way, Fall 1973 was when I was working though it myself), I used to cover this in high school precalculus classes in the late 1990s (at one of those math/science state supported boarding schools for gifted students) -- see my handout from those classes, [Proving Irrationality by the Rational Roots Theorem](https://web.archive.org/web/20180920173958/http://mathforum.org/kb/servlet/JiveServlet/download/13-2001716-6886991-573527/rational%20root%20theorem.pdf).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I really appreciate all your time, I'm going to go and purchase the Numbers book and work my way through it. Regarding a "brush-up" up until calculus, I just read through the table of contents of the above book and realized it doesn't cover too much -- doesn't do logarithms, trig, etc. Is there a good book you can suggest for something covering everything from pre-algebra up through pre-calculus?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro finally, want to put that together in an answer and I can go ahead and accept it?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro by the way I went ahead and bought that math book so will start on it tomorrow! Why don't you suggest going past chapter 5 in it?